# Should the tag "heterodox" have subcategories?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

The [heterodox](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heterodox) is used for non-Orthodox movements. Would it make sense to create a separate Reform tag and a Conservative tag?

Comment: @msh210 - Why did you remove the tag for feature-request? Is a tag not a feature?

Comment: Counter example! http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12780/accusations-against-the-zohar-hakadosh#comment20599_12780

Comment: @AdamMosheh: The SE staff look at the [meta-tag:feature-request] questions, because they're meant as requests for features to be added to the site software.

Comment: @DoubleAA, right, I used the tag there for heterodoxy, not for any "movement".

Comment: AdamMosheh, do you also want a Karite tag, and a non-affiliated tag?

Comment: @DoubleAA ...and Reconstructionist, Jewish Renewal, and Traditional Judaism tags?

Comment: @DoubleAA - There are questions here dealing with Karaism, aren't there?

Comment: [Samaritans-Shomronim-Cutheans-Kutim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17915/shomronim-and-halakha)

Comment: Why does this question have a net vote total of -4? Is downvoting a way to say "no"? I thought answers were how we did that?

Comment: @SAH, yes, "[voting is different on Meta.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions currently tagged this way don't seem to be (mostly) about movements.  The tag needs a tag wiki to be sure, but I think movement-specific tags are an orthogonal consideration.  (As for whether we need those, I think we can defer that until we have questions that are about those movements.)

Comment: We have questions that deal with Conservative and Reform, but the others... not so much.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, I'm not opposed to creating those tags if we have the questions to support them; I just don't think it has much of anything to do with [tag:heterodox].  (And this reminds me that I still owe a meta post about Isaac's Conservative question from the town hall, which I'd like to have a broader discussion about.)

Comment: @MC - Heterodox simply means non-Orthodox, so it does have what to do with them.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, look at the questions currently tagged that way and I think you'll see what I mean.  Also, I meant that the decision to create them is what doesn't have a lot to do with the existing tag; sorry if that wasn't clear.